# How to optimize images uploaded by the user and also existing images on the server in Meteor

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, meteor

Currently my group runs a meteor app with hundreds of thousands of images that are all very large full size. We should have done this a long time ago but we are in need of a way to optimize them to help loading times. I’m looking for a solution to be able to save the image in several sizes when the user uploads it from our app (ex: full-size, medium, thumbnail) and also auto rotate and allow user to rotate. We use Amazon S3 to host all of our images. We also need a way to convert all of the existing images into these size formats from server side.

I tried implementing something a while back and it was unsuccessful. I set up imagemagick on our server but had trouble getting this to work in production because the image was being saved temporarily on server memory to process but this was causing crashes because of limited amount of memory. I have little experience with this kind of thing.

My second thought was to use HTML canvas to resize the images. This would work, I think, for newly uploaded images. But I am still searching for a way to process the existing images as well.

I have considered:

- Maybe AWS has a built in way to process them. I wouldn’t mind doing it that way.
- Some sort of Meteor/node package that can help with this.
- Setting up another server just to process images.
- Using some third party image processing.

If someone can give me some advice so I can get the ball rolling that would be so helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways on two completely different budgets:

1. This is not a way I recommend unless you only have 1-2 GBs (https://transloadit.com/demos/file-importing/resize-all-images-in-an-s3-bucket/)
2. Link your S3 to a Cloudinary service and do the transformations with Cloudinary (you will not like it ($$) for the number of images you have).
3. In AWS, I hope you use Cloudfront to serve your assets. Regardless of the transformation technology you will mainly do 2 things:

   - Create 1 Lambda function for transformation of all new created assets in S3. What I do is to "monitor" an S3 bucket and all new things coming in trigger my Lambda function and I create the assets in 2 other folders and I end up with: full res, half res and thumb res. In Meteor you then link every size to what you need. The most typical case is when you have a user profile image that you need to see it as full header, listing, or small thumb in a chat.
   - Create 1 Lambda Edge (slightly more $$ I believe) and attach to your Cloudfront edge to respond to all calls. If storage cost is not too high for you for the present volume stored, you can transform your images as they are being requested and replace the old larger images, rather than run it in a bulk as a 1 time process.

Instead of Lambda Edge, you could probably set up a EC2 machine with Node and run a function to loop through all your S3 assets and do the transformation.

Anyway, I feel that what you want to do it is all AWS, not related to your Meteor. One more thing to do: optimize images before they are being uploaded. If you use React with Meteor I could provide you with the necessary components, otherwise I can give you the components and you write the Blaze view layer or anything else you may use.

I have the Lambda transformation functions in production based on ImageMagic in case you are interested to go this way. I am also planning to "upgrade" this function to use Sharp (like in the example) but for the time being it is doing great in production, will switch when I get some time.
Check this example:

```
  Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket or folder.

  const dstKeyResizedHalf = `p-half/` + imageName
  s3.getObject({
    Bucket: srcBucket,
    Key: srcKey
  }).promise()
    .then(data => Sharp(data.Body)
      .jpeg({
        chromaSubsampling: '4:4:4',
        progressive: true
      })
      .resize(WEB_WIDTH_MAX)
      .toFormat('jpg')
      .toBuffer()
    )
    .then(buffer => s3.putObject({
      Body: buffer,
      Bucket: dstBucket,
      ContentType: 'image/jpg',
      Key: dstKeyResizedHalf,
      CacheControl: 'max-age=864000'
    }).promise())
    .catch(err => callback(err))
}
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you. I think maybe after reading through responses and checking out some pages online, Lambda is the way to go. Triggering the Lambda function on image request for the older images is a brilliant solution.

Comment: If you decide to go with Lambda please let me know and I will provide you with the necessary bits if you need.

Comment: So, wanted to update on this. I did end up going the Lambda route and it is working great. I set up an API Gateway to trigger the Lambda function. This was the best way for me so that I can get feedback on my apps end that the image transformation is finished and successful. I also ended up setting up a cron process to transform the existing images using the API gateway again. It is working great so far. So, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

[libvips](http://libvips.github.io/libvips/) can resize images without using memory or disk --- pixels are streamed through the system in small chunks, with decode and recode happening at the same time.

For example, with a 10k x 10k pixel JPG image, I see:

```
$ vipsheader wtc.jpg 
wtc.jpg: 9372x9372 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, jpegload
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e vipsthumbnail wtc.jpg -s 5000x5000 -o x.jpg
98720:0.65
```

This is a 4-core, 8-thread i7. It's using 98MB of memory and takes 0.65s of real time. There's a [chapter in the docs introducing vipsthumbnail](http://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Using-vipsthumbnail.md.html).

For comparison, with ImageMagick 6 I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e convert wtc.jpg -resize 5000x5000 x.jpg
1263232:2.02
```

1.3GB of memory and it takes 2s of real time -- about 10x more memory and 3x slower.

Because vipsthumbnail uses so little memory, you can combine it with GNU parallel without needing a server with many, many GB of memory. On this i7, I can usefully run four at once and get a roughly 4x speedup, so perhaps 12x faster than ImageMagick overall.

[sharp is a popular node binding for libvips](https://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/), which might be more convenient. There are bindings for Python, Ruby, PHP, Go, Lua, etc. etc. as well.

(disclaimer: I'm one of the libvips maintainers, so I'm not very neutral)

Comment: Thanks. This does look like a really good option! Seems to check all the boxes. We will give this a try. I want to see what other options may come up before I mark this as the answer though. My biggest concern is how long it would take to process the existing images, although I can't expect it to be fast with the amount of images we currently have. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use https://www.imagemagick.org/ to resize, crop, rotate my images. it works with meteor. This will be good start point to explore.
https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS

Comment: Omgabee wrote in the question, that `imagemagick` causes memory related issues, due to the temporarily saving of copies of images in memory.

Comment: My image usage is limited so I didn't face any issue till now.